# Multiple divs with different data from xml stream

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to have 5 div boxes which decreases(10%) in size. The content for the div comes in from a live stream, where when ever a new node is created in the XML stream, a new div is created and the old one moves ahead, and the last one disappears.
I have written the code for the divs to insert data from multiple xml files(eg. 5 divs have 5 xml files), but would like this real time. 
Ive looked into using carousels in both jquery and css, but I dont know how to trigger an event that will cause the first one to appear. This is my output till now

The link is at **54.165.56.16**

The  portion at the bottom is what i need to fix.
Even if you can point me in the right direction, it would be helpful.

Please help.

Comment: Where is the code you have now?

Comment: its on http://madiralekh.com/twit/code.txt Its the full page code. I have made the divs smaller by coding it in. So need alot of help.

Comment: Hi @Esa have you had a change to look at the code?

Comment: Im sorry but your question is too broad, you don't have a problem that needs fixing, you have a feature that is not implemented. And you have not provided us with what you have tried so far yourself to achieve this impelentation.